# Is it correct to do a one tailed test based on observed direction?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Suppose I am testing whether there is a difference between the mean of two normally distributed variables `X` and `Y`, where `X ~ N(u_1, 1)`, `Y ~ N(u_2, 1)`. Is it theoretically correct if I compute the p-value as `P(X-Y > delta_xy)` if the observed `delta_xy` is positive, and `P(X-Y < delta_xy)` if the observed `delta_xy` is negative? Here `delta_xy` is the difference between the sample mean of `X` and `Y`. In other words, can I do a one-tailed test based on the direction already been observed?

It is of note that if I compute the p-value like this, the "worst" p-value I can get is 0.5, instead of 1. How to explain this?

// Following whuber's comment as an "post hoc testing", I give an example as represented in the boxplot, in which we first plot the data and see there is a difference in the mean, most likely we will do a test of `mean(OJ) > mean(VC)` instead of `mean(OJ) != mean(VC)`, is this an "post hoc testing" abuse?

[image]

Comment: This isn't a good question for our site, because (1) the answer simply is "no" and (2) you can find many explanations in existing threads by means of a site search.  Sometimes the search terms aren't self-evident though, so I have chosen a duplicate found by searching "post hoc hypothesis."

Comment: Thank you whuber. I added another example in the description and will be greateful if you can clarify

Comment: That's definitely *post hoc*; the direction in the hypothesis came *after you looked at the data*. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testing_hypotheses_suggested_by_the_data ... Your explicit hypotheses should be in place before you even collect the data.